# Wordpress - adding a custom font via font-face

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I've built a front-end site which I'm now uploading to wordpress using the html5blank theme. I've never uploaded a custom font file before and I think I'm getting the file path wrong. 
The font-files are in a fonts folder in my child theme folder. This is how I have my code -

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Light';
    src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I've also put this in my `header.php` (not sure it's required) -

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf" />
```

How do I show the correct path if that's what the issue is? Can it be relative or does it need to be absolute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an absolute path in your @font-face here:

```
src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype');
```

The `/` at the start means that its looking for the font in the webroot.

Assuming your style.css is in your child theme folder and `fonts` is a subfolder of that, try this (i.e. without the `/` at the start):

```
src: url('fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype');
```

Comment: fonts isn't a sub folder of style.css , does it need to be? Also, the fonts folder isn't showing in my dashboard>Appearance>Editor , should it be? (It's definitely in the right themes folder.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead no, it doesn't need to be in a subfolder, but you need to include the path to where ever it is in your CSS! You said in your question that the fonts are in the fonts folder of your child theme though... so where is your style if its not in your child theme folder?

Comment: I thought you meant the fonts as a subfolder of the CSS folder - sorry. Your answer got things working - thank you. Now I just need to get my javascript working haha:)

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the address of font file not the stylesheet.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri('/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') ?>/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just put the font inside a folder named `fonts` in your theme directory.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'gothamlight';  
src: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf);  
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Many thanks. So, it has to be an absolute url then? For development purposes I need to put localhost:8888 ?

Comment: I think you can use `<?php echo 'http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>` for that, but not in css file ;)